# Core Data Programming Guide: Merging Changes with Transient Properties

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm currently reading through Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/) and came across *Merging Changes with Transient Properties* (last paragraph of [Managed Objects and References](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/MO_Lifecycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH31-SW1)). It deals with Core Data's transient properties in conjunction with `awakeFromFetch()` and `refresh(_:mergeChanges:)`.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce the described behavior. Taking into account that the guide seems to be inadequate in some areas, I wonder whether the contents of that paragraph are correct at all.

I use the `Single View Application` template with `Use Core Data` checked to validate the assertions:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // check properties and fire faults
    func check(_ person: Person) {
        print("   check:  \(person.firstName ?? "nil") | \(person.lastName ?? "nil") | \(person.fullName ?? "nil")\n")
    }

    // clear persistent store
    let viewContext = persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = Person.fetchRequest()
    let batchDeleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
    try! persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.execute(batchDeleteRequest, with: viewContext)

    // insert person
    print("#  persistent store: insert\n")
    weak var person = Person(context: viewContext)
    person!.firstName = "Sarit"
    person!.lastName = "Smith"
    check(person!)
    try! viewContext.save()

    // create background contexts
    let context1 = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
    let context2 = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()

    // run test
    context2.performAndWait {
        print("#  context2: fetch\n")
        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
        let person = try! context2.fetch(fetchRequest).first!
        check(person)

        context1.performAndWait {
            print("#  context1: fetch\n")
            let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
            let person = try! context1.fetch(fetchRequest).first!
            check(person)
            print("#  context1: modify\n")
            person.firstName = "Fiona"
            check(person)
            try! context1.save()
        }

        print("#  persistent store: check\n")
        viewContext.performAndWait {
            let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
            let person = try! viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest).first!
            check(person)
        }

        print("#  context2: modify\n")
        person.lastName = "Jones"
        check(person)
        print("#  context2: refresh\n")
        context2.refresh(person, mergeChanges: true)
        check(person)
    }

    return true
}
```

**Person+CoreDataClass.swift**

```
override public func awakeFromFetch() {
    super.awakeFromFetch()
    print("-> awakeFromFetch\n")
    print("   before: \(firstName ?? "nil") | \(lastName ?? "nil") | \(fullName ?? "nil")")
    fullName = "\(firstName!) \(lastName!)"
    print("   after:  \(firstName ?? "nil") | \(lastName ?? "nil") | \(fullName ?? "nil")\n")
}
```

**Output**

```
#  persistent store: insert    
   check:  Sarit | Smith | nil

#  context2: fetch    
-> awakeFromFetch    
   before: Sarit | Smith | nil
   after:  Sarit | Smith | Sarit Smith    
   check:  Sarit | Smith | Sarit Smith

#  context1: fetch    
-> awakeFromFetch    
   before: Sarit | Smith | nil
   after:  Sarit | Smith | Sarit Smith    
   check:  Sarit | Smith | Sarit Smith

#  context1: modify 
   check:  Fiona  | Smith | Sarit Smith (1.)
   // (1.) [...] which causes the cached fullName to be updated to "Fiona Smith"[...]

#  persistent store: check    
-> awakeFromFetch    
   before: Fiona | Smith | nil
   after:  Fiona | Smith | Fiona Smith    
   check:  Fiona | Smith | Fiona Smith

#  context2: modify    
   check:  Sarit | Jones | Sarit Smith (1.)
   // (1.) [...] which causes the cached fullName to be updated to "Sarit Jones".

#  context2: refresh    
-> awakeFromFetch    
   before: Fiona | Smith | nil
   after:  Fiona | Smith | Fiona Smith    
-> awakeFromFetch    
   before: Fiona | Jones | Sarit Smith (2.)
   after:  Fiona | Jones | Fiona Jones (3.)   
   check:  Fiona | Jones | Fiona Jones (3.)
   // The transient value, fullName, was also changed prior to the refresh.
   // (2.) After the refresh, its value is restored to "Sarit Jones".
   // (3.) However, to be correct, it should be "Fiona Jones".
```

Findings following the comparison of the generated output with the excerpt from the guide:

1. A change doesn't cause, as stated, the cached transient derived property to be updated automatically.
2. The transient value is restored to *Sarit Smith* initially, instead of *Sarit Jones*.
3. Contrary to the claim made by the guide, `awakeFromFetch()` is called a second time after prerefresh values were applied, updating the transient value correctly.

Am I overlooking something? Is my code the problem? Is the paragraph simply inadequate?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Also having trouble with this section in the docs. Any progress, what where your conclusions?